# Need to compare old post meta value with new post meta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a serious problem concerning postmeta table (wordpress),
i have a field in the table called `_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id` has a specific value and when i click the 'update post' button i want to know the old value of the field `_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id` and the new one to be able to compare them each other to catch if value changed.
Thanks in advance.

**ps:** I tried wordpress actions(hooks) "post_updated" , "save_post" but without result

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'insert',$post_id,3);


 function insert( $post_id, $post_before, $post_after) {

    global $wpdb;
    global $compare_id_outside;


    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($post_before);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($post_after);
    echo '</pre>';


    $req_outside = "SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = " . $post_before->ID . " and `meta_key` = '_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id'";
    $artiste_id_outside = $wpdb->get_results( $req_outside );
    echo $artiste_id_outside[0]->meta_value;



    $req_outside2 = "SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = " . $post_after->ID . " and `meta_key` = '_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id'";
    $artiste_id_outside2 = $wpdb->get_results( $req_outside2 );
    echo $artiste_id_outside2[0]->meta_value;


            //Get Related Artistes to Oeuvre inserted
            $requete = "select wp_postmeta.meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = " . $post_id . "  and meta_key = '_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id'";
            $artiste_id_arr = $wpdb->get_results( $requete );

            if(!$artiste_id_arr && !count($artiste_id_arr))
                return;

            $artiste_id = $artiste_id_arr[0]->meta_value;



            $requete = "select wp_postmeta.meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = " . $post_id . "  and meta_key = '_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id'";
            $artiste_id_arr = $wpdb->get_results( $requete );
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
           $req2 = "SELECT user_id FROM wp_gd_mylist WHERE item_id = $artiste_id";
            $users_id = $wpdb->get_results( $req2 );


            for ($i=0; $i <count($users_id) ; $i++) { 

                echo '<br>';


                $req3 = "SELECT user_email FROM wp_users WHERE ID = " . $users_id[$i]->user_id;
                $users_email_arr = $wpdb->get_results( $req3 );

                $users_email = $users_email_arr[0]->user_email;

                $req_name_arr = "SELECT display_name FROM wp_users WHERE ID = " . $users_id[$i]->user_id;
                $users_name = $wpdb->get_results( $req_name_arr );

                $users_name = $users_name[0]->display_name;

                $email=$users_email;
                $subject="Nouvelle Oeuvre sur le site!";
                $message = "Une nouvelle oeuvre de l'artiste que vous suivez " . $users_name . " a été rajoutée dans le site, voici le lien vers l'oeuvre : " . get_permalink($post_id);
                $headers = 'From:' . "vosartistes.com@gmail.com";
                wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

            }
```

Comment: Inside `post_updated` you get the old and the new post object - but that probably doesn’t include most of the post meta data, and if you start making SQL queries to read this meta data now, at that point it is too late already - you’ll always be reading the already updated data. You should go with something like `pre_post_update`, that fires _before_ the actual database updates are made.

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for your comment. i tried it but got the same result, when i click update post i got always the updated values.

Comment: Show your code then, and explain what you did.

Comment: i putted the details in the Answer Section.

Comment: That’s not where they belong – this is a Q&A site, so what gets posted as an anser, should actually _be_ an answer to the question. Please remove that, and _edit_ your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the code below. I got a specific artist name (I have artist name as field in wp_postmeta table) and when I change the artist name and click update post button i got the new artist name not the OLD one.

```
function do_something_with_a_post($post_id, $post_data) {
    global $wpdb;

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($post_data);
    echo '</pre>';

    $requete = "select wp_postmeta.meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = " . $post_id . "  and meta_key = '_wpcf_belongs_artiste_id'";
    $artiste_id_arr = $wpdb->get_results( $requete );
    $artiste_id = $artiste_id_arr[0]->meta_value;

    echo $artiste_id;

    die();
}

add_action('pre_post_update', 'do_something_with_a_post', $post_id, 2);
```

Thanks for your HELP.